# У меня не работает value

Tags: javascript

Задаю тут свой первый вопрос, надеюсь понятно всё сформулировала. Если что, извините, буду уточнять. Добавлю сюда кусочки кода, которые считаю необходимыми для понимания проблемы. Если что-то ещё нужно добавить, подскажите.

```
<form class="add">
    <div class="promo__interactive-title">ДОБАВИТЬ НОВЫЙ ФИЛЬМ</div>
          <span>Введите название фильма</span>
            <input class="adding__input" type="text" placeholder="Что уже посмотрено...?">
             <span>Сделать его любимым?</span>
             <input type="checkbox">
             <span class="yes">Да!</span>
             <button>Подтвердить</button>
</form>
```

и надо сделать так (этот кусок кода будет приведен ниже), чтобы после нажатия на кнопку надо было добавлять фильм в список, но это сейчас не совсем важно, важно то, что на определенной строке кода происходит непонятная ошибка и value просто не считывается, когда я ввожу название фильма и жму кнопку подтвердить. Почему так происходит? Что нужно, чтобы этой ошибки не было?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at HTMLFormElement.

```
const advs = document.querySelectorAll('.promo__adv img'),
          poster = document.querySelector('.promo__bg'),
          genre = poster.querySelector('.promo__genre'),
          movieList = document.querySelector('.promo__interactive-list'),
          addForm = document.querySelector('.add'),
          addInput = addForm.querySelector('.adding_input'),
          checkbox = addForm.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');
    
    addForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();

       const newFilm = addInput.value;
       const favorite = checkbox.checked;

       movieDB.movies.push(newFilm);
       sortArr(movieDB.movies);

       createFilmsList(movieDB.movies, movieList);

       event.target.reset();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо написать `querySelector('.adding__input')`, а не `querySelector('.adding_input')`

Comment: Твою мышь! Моё сильнейшее чувство стыда за свою очередную невнимательность, перекрывает лишь моя сильнейшая благодарность вам за помощь!) Спасибо большое! Я исправила и всё заработало. Ужас какой, постараюсь быть более внимательной. Ещё раз спасибо!